# B Tree node splitting based on order of the tree. Data Structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

I have came across a question of B Tree which goes like:

10. Which of the following is true?

a) larger the order of B-tree, less frequently the split occurs

b) larger the order of B-tree, more frequently the split occurs

c) smaller the order of B-tree, more frequently the split occurs

d) smaller the order of B-tree, less frequently the split occurs

The answer given online is a with the explanation of,

Answer: a

Explanation: The average probability of the split is 1/(⌈m / 2⌉ – 1), where m is the order of B-tree. So, if m larger, the probability of split will be less.

My doubt is if 'larger order makes less frequent splits' then why not 'smaller order makes more frequent splits', If one statement is true isn't it by default that the opposite will be true also?

Comment: You are correct and this is a terrible question.